# "Lost and Found" by trenitalia?

Tags: trains, italy, trenitalia

I sadly lost my camera bag with my full camera stuff in the train which went to milano.
But it was nearly impossible to get my stuff back or get some informations what should I do in Milano, because everything were closed and the guys at the police station weren't very motivated to help me...

Now I'm back in my home country and I'm searching for a way to get my camera back and searched for a "Lost and Found"-Number or mail, sadly I only found [this article](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g187791-i22-k3734057-No_way_to_get_your_bags_back_if_you_lose_them_on_trains-Rome_Lazio.html), which says I can write off my camera...
But this article is from 2010, maybe today it is possible?

Do someone know what can I do now to get my camera back?
(Lost: 10.10.2014 in train from Bern (Switzerland) to Milano)

Comment: @pnuts: sadly not

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Milan city council runs a lost&found service](http://www.milanocentrale.it/en/service/detail/oggetti-smarriti/) which can be contacted at these phone numbers:

- +39 02 88453900
- +39 02 88453908
- +39 02 88453909

They advise you to contact "Polizia ferroviara" and file a report before contacting them but since you skipped this step I'd try to contact them anyway.

I wouldn't hold my breath but good luck anyway!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I went to the police station inside the tran station, but they weren't very motivated to help me...

Comment: @dTDesign welcome to Italy! :-)

Answer (score 3):

If your lost bag came back to Bern (and you'd be very lucky) you can try with this web page https://www.ffs.ch/stazione-servizi/servizi/servizio-oggetti-trovati.html
If someone found the bags in Italy. I'm very sad to tell this but will be very hard for you to recover that/

Comment: Thanks, yes I already contacted the Lost and Found of the SBB. And yes I read that many times now... But thank you :)